# How to get the defaultNamingContext in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, com, active-directory, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do ActiveDirectory/LDAP-Authentication in .NET Core. 
However, there is no System.DirectoryServices in **.NET Core (NetStandard 1.6)**.
 
So instead, I use Novell.Directory.Ldap, which works fine, as long as you know the rootDSE.

Normally, I would get the ActiveDirectory RootDSE-defaultNamingContext like this:

```
public static string GetRootDSE()
{
    DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
    string defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value;
    return defaultNamingContext:
}
```

However, since there is no System.DirectoryServices, I can't do that. 
Novell.Directory.Ldap seems not to have an equivalent function for that, or at the very least I can't find it.

Now for example in VBScript, you could get the defaultNamingContext like this:

```
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
strADsPath = "LDAP://" & objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Set objDomain = GetObject(strADsPath)
```

So I tried to use the same COM-Object in C# (since there is no VB.NET for .NET Core, I can't call the VB.NET runtime). 
This is what I have managed to get so far:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Activeds", ExactSpelling = true, 
EntryPoint = "ADsGetObject",
CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int ADsGetObject(string path
    , [System.Runtime.InteropServices.In, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out] ref System.Guid iid
    , [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Out, System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppObject
);


public static void Test()
{
    dynamic ppObject;

    // System.Guid IID_IDirectorySearch = new System.Guid("{ 0x109BA8EC, 0x92F0, 0x11D0, { 0xA7, 0x90, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x4F, 0xD8, 0xD5, 0xA8 } }");
    // System.Guid IID_IADsContainer = new System.Guid("{ 0x001677D0, 0xFD16, 0x11CE, { 0xAB, 0xC4, 0x02, 0x60, 0x8C, 0x9E, 0x75, 0x53 } }");
    System.Guid IID_IADs = new System.Guid("{ 0xFD8256D0, 0xFD15, 0x11CE, { 0xAB, 0xC4, 0x02, 0x60, 0x8C, 0x9E, 0x75, 0x53 } }");
    ADsGetObject("LDAP://rootDSE", ref IID_IADs, out ppObject);
    System.Console.WriteLine(ppObject);

    object objDSE;
    // System.IntPtr objDSE;
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705950(v=vs.85).aspx
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746347(v=vs.85).aspx
    // HRESULT Get( [in]  BSTR    bstrName, [out] VARIANT *pvProp);
    // ppObject.Get("defaultNamingContext", out objDSE);

    System.IntPtr bstr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.
      Marshal.StringToBSTR("defaultNamingContext");
    ppObject.Get(bstr, out objDSE);
    System.Console.WriteLine(objDSE);
}
```

I get the COM-Object ("ppObject"), and it seems to work fine until I call Get on ppObject. 
There I get `"Not Implemented-Exception: Method or process is not implemented."`

What am I doing wrong ?

Also, if anybody has a better way of getting the RootDSE in .NET Core, then I'm all ears.

PS: 
I know this will only work on Windows - I just set it to manually configure on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, never mind, I got the answer:

As you can see [here](http://You%20need%20to%20use%20an%20%60=%60%20after%20%60-type%60:%20%20%20%20%20%20nslookup%20-type=srv%20_ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME), you can run

```
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.DOMAINNAME
```

to get the desired result. 
So when you run

```
nslookup -type=srv _ldap._tcp.YourDomain.local
```

, that means you query the default-DNS for the ldap-server record of the executing machine's domain, and use that result.

You can do that with any .NET Core capable DNS-library, such as ArSoft.

[image: Dig]

```
public static void Test4()
{
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties ipgp = 
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

    // IDnsResolver resolver = new RecursiveDnsResolver(); // Warning: Doesn't work
    IDnsResolver resolver = new DnsStubResolver();

    List<SrvRecord> srvRecords = resolver.Resolve<SrvRecord>("_ldap._tcp." + ipgp.DomainName, RecordType.Srv);

    foreach (SrvRecord thisRecord in srvRecords)
    {
        // System.Console.WriteLine(thisRecord.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine(thisRecord.Target);
        System.Console.WriteLine(thisRecord.Port);

        // Note: OR LDAPS:// - but Novell doesn't want these parts anyway 
        string url = "LDAP://" + thisRecord.Target + ":" + thisRecord.Port; 
        System.Console.WriteLine(url);
    } // Next thisRecord

}
```